# How do I find average of two rows with for loop?

Tags: r

see below the formatting of my data.

```
     Date AMZN.Closing.Price AMZN.Daily.Percent.Return
1 2004-12-31              44.29                        NA
2 2005-01-03              44.52                 0.5193046
3 2005-01-04              42.14                -5.3459119
4 2005-01-05              41.77                -0.8780256
5 2005-01-06              41.05                -1.7237252
6 2005-01-07              42.32                 3.0937881
```

I am trying to find the average daily percent return (example: -5.3459119+0.5193046/2) for all rows.

Here is my current code. I am unsure how to reference all the rows.

```
> for (rows in data$AMZN.Daily.Percent.Return) {return = x[2]+x[3]/2}
> return
[1] -2.153651
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not need to be done with a loop, but

```
data$res=NA
for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {
    data$res[i]=mean(data$AMZN.Daily.Percent.Return[(i-1):i])
}
```

Alternative

```
(tail(data$AMZN.Daily.Percent.Return,-1)+head(data$AMZN.Daily.Percent.Return,-1))/2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rolling functions to take mean for every `n` values. One way using `zoo`'s `rollmeanr`.

```
data$avg_return <- zoo::rollmeanr(data$AMZN.Daily.Percent.Return, 2, fill = NA)
data$avg_return
#[1]         NA         NA -2.4133037 -3.1119687 -1.3008754  0.6850314
```